# Git Bash - Error in push command "CreateProcessW failed error:193"

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash, openssh, github-for-windows

I have been trying to execute some powershell script using Powershell ISE and for that I have been trying to add the SSH-Agent for that - *on which I failed*.

But when I tried to reset my old **.ssh** folder (I kept back of it before I started), it stopped working for my Git Bash and now I cannot push my changes to GitHub.

I have verified [link1](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5641#issuecomment-421801704) but that's correct on my machine.

I have even checked my Environment Variables to make sure no unnecessary Git path set to that and that's on the correct side too.

Also, I have tried to `push` the branch by having the OpenSSH service in `Start` and `Stop` state.

Please let me know what check I missed here and how can I solve this issue.

Comment: I ran into the same error today. After some trial and error, I realized that the Windows Service OpenSSH Authentication Agent was set to Disabled for some reason. It could be due to the recent Windows update, but I'm not sure. I had to set the startup to Automatic and then I could start it running. Once it's running, my git commands were working again. Hopefully this will help someone.